# Find and rename all pictures with incorrect file extension

Tags: terminal, grep, find, rename

I'm looking for a way to automate renaming all images with a wrong filename extension. So far I at least found out how to get the list of all these files:

```
find /media/folder/ -name *.jpg -exec file {} \; | grep  'PNG\|GIF' > foobar.txt
find /media/folder/ -name *.png -exec file {} \; | grep 'JPEG\|GIF' >> foobar.txt
find /media/folder/ -name *.gif -exec file {} \; | grep 'JPEG\|PNG' >> foobar.txt
```

However, I would also like to automate the renaming. I tried things like

```
find /media/folder/ -name *.jpg -exec file {} \; | grep -l PNG | rename s/.jpg/.png/
```

but in this case `grep -l` or `grep -lH` don't list only filenames like I thought they would.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `-l` and `-H` flags of `grep` are not useful in your example. These flags have no effect when used with the standard input, like in your example coming from the pipe. These flags only work if you specify files (or directories and the `-r` flag for recursion), for example:

```
grep -rl PNG path/to/dir1 file2 file3
```

In your example the `-l` has no effect, so the output is the complete lines that matched `PNG`, which in your example probably look something like this:

> icon.png: PNG image, 512 x 512, 8-bit/color RGBA, non-interlaced

To get only the filename, maybe you can cut off everything after the colon like this:

```
find /media/folder/ -name *.jpg -exec file {} \; | grep PNG | sed -e s/:.*// | rename s/.jpg/.png/
```

Comment: Thank you, it works this way. I have to go with grep without any arguments since `grep -l` gives me errors in my command as well as in yours but other than that it does exactly what it's supposed to.

Comment: Oh yes, I should not have put the `-l` in my last example, that was just a copy and paste mistake... (fixed it now)

Answer (score 0):

First off you likely need -iname which ignores case.
Secondly, all that grep stuff seems rather awkward.  Why not simply use -exec mv?

Try creating a file, call it mypicfix:

```
#/bin/bash
FROM=$1; 
[ -f $1 ] || exit
TO=$(echo $1 | sed s/JPG$/jpg/); 
mv "$FROM" "$TO" }
```

SAVE; then

```
chmod +x mypicfix
```

Then run find /tmp -iname '*.jpg' -exec ./mypicfix {} ;

N.B. Find does not take functions or aliases in the -exec parameter, so I had to create a short executable file for it.  Otherwise there are many other ways.   Like, find /tmp -iname *.jpg | while read i do; mv "$i" "$(echo $i | sed s/JPG$/jpg/)"; done