# pipe output of "file" to "mv" to rename files with file-extension

Tags: bash

Following situation:
A folder with many different image-files in it: jpeg, png, gif
The output of file * looks something like:

```
filename1: png image data, 300 x 300, some more information bla bla
filename2: gif image data, 300 x 300, some more information bla bla
filename3: jpeg image data, 300 x 300, some more information bla bla
```

Now, the best way would be to just append a suffix to the files (like image.png) because the files are named like "avatar_pobmglinmphfhbiffgmdmphklcbjolklmnaeblbk".
So the problem is that there's no option (afaik) with the command "file" to output only the filetype and filename/-path

My imagination is something with pipes or find -exec with file inside.

Thank you very much in advance for your help!

Comment: See: [Find and rename all pictures with incorrect file extension](http://stackoverflow.com/q/15180099/3776858)

Comment: The output of the `file` command is meant to be human-readable, not necessarily machine parsable.  If you manage to parse its output, I suggest using it to create a script that you carefully check before executing it; the script would then rename the files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `read` and [process substitution](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ProcessSubstitution) :

```
while IFS=' ' read img ext n; do
  mv ${img%:} ${img%:}.${ext}
done < <(file *)
```

The `${img%:}` syntax is part of the [shell parameter expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html). It strips trailing `:` from image names.

The process substitution `<(file *)` allows to handle a command output as a file. The `file *` output is redirected here as input for the `read` command.

Comment: i understand nearly everything (with very less experience with loops) except the % in front of the colon inside the curly brackets and the < <(file *) part after done. but it doesn't work `mv: rename icon_1158036545: PNG image data, 16 x 16, 8-bit/color RGBA, non-interlaced to icon_1158036545: PNG image data, 16 x 16, 8-bit/color RGBA, non-interlaced.: No such file or directory` what is incorrect?

Comment: I've added some explanations and updated the script (set  the `IFS` to space).

Comment: it works! thank you very much! is the n variable (i think it is one?) to catch the rest of the lines which is junk in this usage or has it some more things to do? furthermore i will read the man of `read` to get a better general understanding of all in this loop.
thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: You're welcome! You're right about the `n` variable, it's just used here to catch the rest of the lines, nothing else.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `mv` + `cut` :

```
IFS=$'\n'
for line in $(file *); do 
  filename=$(echo $line | cut -d: -f1)
  extension=$(echo $line | cut -d' ' -f2)
  mv $filename "${filename}.${extension}"
done
```

Comment: this is a script solution, isn't it? can i write this in a one-liner directly in bash shell? something like:

for line in $(file *); do filename=$(echo $line | cut -f1 | tr -d ':') && extension=$(echo $line | cut -f2) && mv $filename "${filename}.${extension}"; done;

would that be correct?
thanks

Comment: 1) You can write this in bash shell without the need to make it into a 1-liner ; 2) a better 1-liner would be `for line in $(file *); do mv $(echo $line | cut -f1 | tr -d ':') "$(echo $line | cut -f1 | tr -d ':').$(echo $line | cut -f2)"; done` but yeah, yours looks correct

Comment: it doesn't work...

`mv: rename PNG to PNG.PNG: No such file or directory
mv: rename image to image.image: No such file or directory
mv: rename data, to data,.data,: No such file or directory
mv: rename 300 to 300.300: No such file or directory
mv: rename x to x.x: No such file or directory`

looks like there's something incorrect in the cut -f1/-f2 section(s)...

Comment: Ok, there were two problems : `for` looped on words rather than lines, and `cut` cut around tabs rather than space; I've updated my answer to account for both

Comment: thank you very much, it works! i've tried to replace the tr command with a colon as delimter in the first cut command, so something like: `IFS=$'\n' && for line in $(file *); do filename=$(echo $line | cut -d: -f1) && extension=$(echo $line | cut -d' ' -f2) && mv $filename "${filename}.${extension}"; done` did you use the tr command to allow colons in filenames? another question is, why do i need the curly brackets in the second half of mv? `mv $filename "${filename}.${extension}"`? is this to take the variables instead of the $filename of bash? (is $filename from bash?) thank you very much!

Comment: No, I've just used the `tr` to remove the `:` from the `file *` output : since it's just next to the file name, `cut -d' ' -f1` outputs it. I actually don't think i needed to use `${var}` here, but it makes it clearer what the variables are. It's necessary when a character you want after a variable could be part of the variable name : for example `echo "$homesweethome"` would display nothing since `$homesweethome` isn't defined, while `echo "${home}sweethome"` would display something like `/home/Aaronsweethome`

Comment: Btw for the `:` part, it would actually be smarter to use `cut -d: -f1` to retrieve the filename.

Comment: another problem occurred now: in some files there are comments which contain `"` and i think they are responsible for `cut: stdin: Illegal byte sequence`. can i somehow escape the `"`? it doesn't work with `'` in the second argument of mv.

Comment: `cut` is only handling the file names, not their content. I've no idea what might be causing this here, but you could try to debug the command either by using `bash -x` or by displaying the `$line` when `cut` returns an error code